# Cant run JavaScript from view in asp.net MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i want run JavaScript/jQuery from view but didn't show me anything. my code work and data is recorded  in database but don't know why JavaScript/jQuery didn't work

my code are:

Action Code:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(User user)
    {
        UserRepository blUser = new UserRepository();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (blUser.Add(user))
            {
                return Json(new JsonData() { Success = true });// return {"Success":true}
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(new JsonData() { Success = false }); // return {"Success":false}
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(new JsonData() { Success = false }); // return {"Success":false}
        }
}
```

and view code:

```
@section Scripts {

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#reg-btn").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "Post",
                url: "/Home/Register",
                data: null,
                dataTpe: "Json",
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result.Success == true) {
                        alert("success");
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("error");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>}
```

nothing happen when submit button pressed just data record in database  ... just in new page show me " {"Success":true} "  if i removed this line code in view:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
```

still didn't work if i changed return  in controller

```
return JavaScript("alert('success')"); // again show string "alert('success')" in new page if above line code removed
```

and partial view too...

which  JavaScript reference file added to my project? default created by visual studio 2015 / MVC 4 + jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js

ty

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` should be inside the click event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem.
just in `Ajax.BeginForm` method, i added `OnSuccess` and `OnFailure` properties to `AjaxOptions` ... and defined 2 functions for both in script section

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Register",new AjaxOptions {
    OnSuccess = "OnSuccess",
    OnFailure = "OnFailure"
}))
{
```

and in script section

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OnSuccess(response) {  
            alert("done");
    }
    function OnFailure(response) {
            alert("error");    
    }
</script>
```

I hope this answer will help others in the future

Answer (score 0):

Your `e.preventDefault()` is in wrong place and is likely throwing error in dev tools console

Change

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#reg-btn").click(function () {
       ....
```

To

```
$(document).ready(function () {        
    $("#reg-btn").click(function () {
       e.preventDefault();
       ....
```